# Issue with Inheritance in Python - Unable to Access Parent Class Method

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance, methods, constructor

I'm currently working on a Python project where I'm using inheritance to create a base class and a derived class. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to access a method from the parent class within the child class.

```
class MyBaseClass:
def __init__(self, name):
self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        return f"Hello, {self.name}!"

class MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass):
def __init__(self, name, age):
super().__init__(name)
self.age = age

    def display_info(self):
        # Problematic line
        greeting = self.greet()  # This results in an AttributeError
    
        return f"{greeting} I am {self.age} years old."

obj = MyDerivedClass("John", 25)
print(obj.display_info())
```

Issue:

The problem occurs when trying to call the greet method from the `MyBaseClass` within the `display_info` method of the `MyDerivedClass`. The code raises an `AttributeError` stating that the method does not exist.

I expected the greet method to be accessible from the child class, as it's defined in the parent class. Am I missing something in my inheritance setup, or is there a scoping issue?

What I've Tried:

1. Ensured that the parent class (MyBaseClass) is properly initialized using super() in the child class constructor.

Comment: Why is question tagged both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x? Which are you using?

Comment: Please fix the formatting and indentation of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and you have access to your parent class methods because of the `super()` constructor of your parent class. But your formatting and indentation may cause this error. You can fix in this way:

```
class MyBaseClass:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
   def greet(self):
      return f"Hello, {self.name}!"

class MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass):
   def __init__(self, name, age):
      super().__init__(name)
      self.age = age

   def display_info(self):
      greeting = self.greet()

      return f"{greeting} I am {self.age} years old."

obj = MyDerivedClass("John", 25)
print(obj.display_info())
```